# How to use mockery to mock global class without namespace?

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, mockery

I would like to test my WordPress application which calls this function https://github.com/Automattic/WPCOM-Related-Posts/blob/master/wpcom-related-posts.php

I'm not sure how to mock that because WPCom_Related_Posts is not namespaced.

This is how I use the class

```
$related_posts = WPCom_Related_Posts()->get_related_posts( get_queried_object_id(), $args );
```

How should I mock this `get_related_posts` in the test because this class will call Elasticsearch to get related posts and I don't want to set that up in PHPUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward: the same way as you'd mock any other class:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('WPCom_Related_Posts');
//or, if you want to be explicit:
$mocl = Mockery::mock('\WPCom_Related_Posts');
```

There's quite a lot of [documentation along with examples](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/startup_methods.html) about this, on the first page, for example:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('stdClass');
```

That ought to have answered your question (`stdClass` isn't namespaced either (well, it's in the global NS).

Don't forget to run `\Mockery::close();` at the end of each test, though (in the `tearDown` or `_after`, or whatever it's called in the test framework you're using). Especially when you start using expectations